# Maximizing the trace of product of matrices under fixed spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, maxima-minima, trace

Is it correct that under fixed spectrum, $\operatorname{tr}(AB)$ is maximized when $A$ and $B$ share the same eigenbasis? If yes, how can this be shown?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. The fact you are looking for is called the Von Neumann's trace inequality. I am not familiar with its proof(s).

Comment: @AnonymousCoward von Neumann's trace inequality is about *singular values*, not eigenvalues.

Comment: *"Under fixed spectrum"* of what? Do you mean the spectrum of $AB$ is fixed? Or the spectra of $A$ and $B$ are fixed? Or something else?

Comment: @AnonymousCoward Sorry, but I don't follow. Would you please be more specific?

Comment: @user1551By fixed spectrum I meant that we fix the singular values of either matrix, say A.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward In fact, the matrices in my problem happen to be real and symmetric, so the eigenvalues and singular values coincide. Thanks for your help!